# How to start/stop or restart c# console app by another mono GUI in LInux(Ubuntu)?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, console, mono

Is there a way to start/stop/restart c# console app by another mono based GUI app in Linux(Ubuntu)? Basically mono based GUI is for the configuration and after the configuration I would like to start other console app by pressing the start button. Any insights/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried 'Process.Start()' ?

Comment: The c# application is an executable (exe file) like any other executable on Ubuntu and can be called many different ways depending on the program language you are using.  See : https://askubuntu.com/questions/142092/how-do-i-run-an-executable-file-with-a-double-click?force_isolation=true

Comment: @puko yep, I am using Process to start the program.

Comment: @jdweng  I changed the directory permission to run executable but still getting "<pre>System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000022 from typeref (expected class &apos;System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler&apos; in assembly &apos;System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;)
</pre> exceptions. Thank you anyways!

Comment: You need to download the correct version of core runtime.  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1?force_isolation=true

Comment: You should first migrate everything to .NET 6, and then the discussion might become meaningful. Mono is known to have more and more issues like that, as it is no longer actively maintained. One of the biggest Mono based applications, VS for Mac, has just moved to .NET 6, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/mac-release-notes-preview#1700-pre5--visual-studio-2022-for-mac-version-170-preview-5-newreleasebutton